# WPF Window has two arrows on the left upper site when starting program?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I changed my Window to UserControl :

```
<UserControl x:Class="SessionRater.MainWindow "
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SessionRater"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="525">

<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="projectTitle" Content="Session Rater" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="217,24,192,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panelBttn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="19,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" >
        <Button x:Name="bttnCreateSession" Content="Create new Session" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Height="49" Click="bttnCreateSession_Click" />
        <Separator Opacity="0" Height="25"/>
        <Button x:Name="bttnRateSession" Content="Rate Session" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Height="49" Click="bttnRateSession_Click"/>
        <Separator Opacity="0" Height="25"/>
        <Button x:Name="bttnCloseSession" Content="Close Session" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Height="49"  Click="bttnCloseSession_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="listSessions" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="204" Margin="217,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="262">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="220" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Rating" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Rating}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbListInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="   Overview (Average Rating of each Session)" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="262"/>

</Grid>
```

And now when I always execute my programm I have two arrows appearing on the screen? Why?

[image]

Comment: Try to use the live view (top black bar) and look for yourself :). My theory is that your Usercontrol gets displayed by a frame (as those have these arrows).

Comment: @CShark I changed the UserControl again to Window. Now the Arrows dissapeared but the my setted size (500*525) won't work. The program open the program in the size you can see in the picture

Comment: Thats because it says "d:DesignWidth". Its for the visual studio designer only. If you want to change the real size of your window/control/whatever you need to use "Width"/"Height" instead.

Comment: I had similar problem when i changed some Usercontrols. It turned out that my app.xaml was not starting the mainWindow, but directly the first Usercontrol. It seems that Usercontrols can be directly invoked in pages